# Event-driven Travis build

Tags: events, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm looking for an "event-driven" way to use travis, I need to notify him when something occurred but in the meanwhile the build should be in 'yellow' state, it may takes up to 2 hours.

Does anybody knows a way? or another CI supports that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can [trigger builds using travis API](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/).

For example, to trigger a build for the most recent commit, you can send the following POST request:

```
body='{
"request": {
"branch":"master"
}}'

curl -s -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Travis-API-Version: 3" \
   -H "Authorization: token xxxxxx" \
   -d "$body" \
   https://api.travis-ci.com/repo/travis-ci%2Ftravis-core/requests
```

Comment: Thank you @TheUnreal ! I'm actually using travis API, what I'm really looking for is for a build to hold until I notify it like in event-driven programming. Perhaps you know other CI for the mission?